# How to get all urls list from the database | MySQL and Next JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, url, next.js, mysql-workbench

I want to take all the urls from my database but i don't know what is the right code to do it.
I've been struggling for 2 days to search but can't figure out how to do it.

This is in my current code in index.js in server folder.
In this file i alse make login and register, just watch tutorial from youtube, don't really know how it works of the dependecies, just a little bit.

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const passport = require("passport");
const expressSession = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const db = require("./db");

const app = express();

app.get("/getUrls", (req, res) => {
    const url = req.body.url;

    const query = "SELECT * FROM db_indexer.urls";
    res.send(query);
});
```

and this is in the front end code.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function processUrl() {

    const [urls, setUrls] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getUrls();
    }, []);

    const getUrls = () => {
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            withCredentials: true,
            url: "http://localhost:3001/getUrls",
        })
            .then((res) => {
                setUrls(res.data.url);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <section className="text-black body-font">
                <div className="container px-5 py-24 mx-auto">
                    <div className="lg:w-2/3 w-full mx-auto overflow-auto">
                        <table className="table-auto w-full text-left whitespace-no-wrap">
                            <thead className="text-center">
                                <tr>
                                    <th className=" px-20 py-3 title-font tracking-wider font-medium text-gray-900 text-sm bg-gray-100 rounded-tl rounded-bl">
                                        Status
                                    </th>
                                    <th className="w-full py-3 title-font tracking-wider font-medium text-gray-900 text-sm bg-gray-100">
                                        Links
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {urls.map((result, id) => {
                                    return (
                                        <tr className="results" key={id}>
                                            <td className="px-4 py-3 text-emerald-500 text-center">
                                                Success
                                            </td>
                                            <td className="px-4 py-3">
                                                <a href={url} target="_blank">
                                                    {result.url}
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    );
                                })}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    );
}
```

anyway my database looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfQik.png)

any solution or if you can fixed my code, it would really help me :)

edit : my error like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY41l.png)

Comment: What is the issue with your current code? Is there a specific error message?

Comment: there is no no specific error message but the data(url) wouldn't appear in the page, so i think i must write the wrong code

Comment: Well you need to actually execute the SQL query.

Comment: owh sorry, there is an error like this ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')```

Comment: You're never actually executing the query. That is a problem.